# Jquery Mobile - Density Independent Pixels

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an android app in PhoneGap . I have to adjust some button sizes  as per the  screen size on which the app is run .In android we have sp  , dpi .Are there any similar type in jquery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I only caught a glimpse of jquery-mobile, as far as I know it does not directly address variable display sizes and pixel densities.

There are other mechanisms to handle this:

- Set the viewport's `target-densitydpi` to `medium-dpi` (=160dpi). This virtualizes the `px` unit, e.g. `1px` in html/css then corresponds to 2 physical pixels on a 320dpi device. Easy solution, but note that images are scaled as well.

  ```
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
  ```
- CSS: Use media queries to implement conditional styling. Adapting for different screen sizes dependent on width, height, aspect or orientation is straight-forward, see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/. 
  Different pixel densities can be handled with `device-pixel-ratio` (thanks to Marc Edwards for providing an example: https://gist.github.com/marcedwards/3446599).

  ```
  @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
         screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 15/10)
  {
    body { background-image: ... } /* provide high-res image */
  }
  ```

  The media feature `resolution` is cleaner than `device-pixel-ratio`, but many browsers don't support it.
- Use Javascript: Adapt button sizes, images etc. based on `window.devicePixelRatio` and `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height`. Layouting per Javascript is considered as bad practice. Also flickering might result during loading as the execution starts after the `pageload` event.